# rails how to validatie data params in method dose not updated, created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to validate 1 params in model method, but i can't found any fit answers , please show me the right way.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :username, presence: true, length: 4..5, unique: true
    validate :email, presence: true, unique: true, format: {with: /\A[a-z0-9\.]+@([a-z]{1,10}\.){1,2}[a-z]{2,4}\z/}
    def self.get_post(id)
        # how to call validate id ??? 
        validates :id, numericality: true
        if id.valid?
            # true code
        else
            # false code
        end
    end
    def change_profile
        # How to check validate user and email
        username.valid?
        email.valid?

        # some_code....

    end
end
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `validates` there, you can do this instead

```
def self.get_post(id)      
  if id.is_a? Numeric
      # true code
  else
      # false code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was modifier my question, I hope you help me. thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use active model for your customization, you can not check validation on field to filed, but you can perform with active model with number of fields as per your requirement

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with UserProfile
end

class UserProfile < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if some_complex_logic
      record.errors[:base] = "This record is invalid"
    end
  end

  private
    def some_complex_logic
      # ...
    end
end
```